# How does item durability affect its performance

Tags: the-witcher-3

In Witcher 3 the item durability is introduced. The items degrade through use up to the point, the items is broken and you can see pictogram in main interface showing it.

How exactly does the durability affects the stats of the item? Broken weapons and armor shows same stats regardless of it's durability.

Comment: Which difficulty? Higher difficulties increase the penalty for damaged or broken equipment.

Comment: I play on easy or normal (I'm not really sure atm). But I would like to know all the effects for reference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Though it does show the same stat, it also shows a negative number in brackets (example below shows: `(-24)`) next to the main stat, with a small hammer icon. This is the degradation, in stat form, and increases proportionally with lost durability.

[image: Example Inventory Item with Degredation]

You'll notice this on both weapons and armour, and is basically a flat negative to any rolled damage / armour value.

Comment: What does the "-62" in your image indicate?

Comment: That's the variation in damage from the currently equipped sword (of that type).